# Find the length of a diagonal of a city block.

Tags: trigonometry

A city block is a square with each side measuring 104 yards. Find the length of the diagonal of a city block.

Answer (score 1):

The diagonal of a square forms a 45-45-90 triangle, with two sides of length $s$ where $s$ is the side length of the square. Then, by either Pythagorean theorem or memorizing the special triangle, the diagonal (hypotenuse of that triangle) has length $s \sqrt{2}$.

Also, "diagonalization" is the wrong tag.

Answer (score 0):

$d$=diagonal

$s$=side

based on Pythagorean theorem will have :

$$d=\sqrt{s^2+s^2}=s\sqrt{2}$$

or based on trigonometry :

$$\sin (\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{s}{d}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\rightarrow d=s\sqrt{2}$$